# Is there an FPRAS for the number of min st cuts in general graphs?

Tags: complexity-theory, approximation, counting, minimum-cuts

Provan and Ball [1] showed that the problem of counting the number of minimum st cuts is #P-Complete. What is known about the problem of approximating the number of min st cuts? Is it possible to get a Fully Polynomial Randomized Approximation Scheme for it?

[1] Provan, J. Scott, and Michael O. Ball. "The complexity of counting cuts and of computing the probability that a graph is connected." SIAM Journal on Computing 12.4 (1983): 777-788.

Answer (score 1):

The Provan and Ball paper actually shows a 1-1 reduction from bipartite independent sets (BIS) to min st cuts. So an FPRAS for min cuts would imply an FPRAS for #BIS. However, #BIS is not known (and thought unlikely) to have an FPRAS [1][2].

[1] Dyer, Martin, et al. "On the relative complexity of approximate counting problems." International Workshop on Approximation Algorithms for Combinatorial Optimization. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2000.

[2] Dyer, Martin, Leslie Ann Goldberg, and Mark Jerrum. "An approximation trichotomy for Boolean# CSP." Journal of Computer and System Sciences 76.3-4 (2010): 267-277.